# can i use select out variable in where condition?

Tags: sql-server

please look my sql statement :

```
declare @rptID as int
declare @lastRptID as int

select  @rptID = 238507
select top 1 @lastRptID = reportid from MeraRpt  where reportid < @rptid order by reportid desc

 SELECT
           @rptid
           ,[BelongTo] as Customer  
           ,[Prefix] as Prefix
           ,sum([ASRSuccessCalls])
        　　, (select sum(ASRSuccessCalls) from [V_MeraRpt_Detail_ByPrefix] a 
            where a.[BelongTo] = Customer and a.[Prefix] = Prefix
            and a.[reportID] in (@rptID,@lastRptID))

      from [V_MeraRpt_Detail_ByPrefix]
      where reportid = @rptid and Customer in (select custid from v_MostUsedCustomer )
      group by [BelongTo],[Prefix]
```

this sql can pass compile and run , but it gives wrong result , the problem is this sentence :

```
(select sum(ASRSuccessCalls) from [V_MeraRpt_Detail_ByPrefix] a 
                where a.[BelongTo] = Customer and a.[Prefix] = Prefix
                and a.[reportID] in (@rptID,@lastRptID))
```

the result is this form :

```
238507  Umobile 23480   1   4294
238507  Umobile 234803  0   4294
238507  Umobile 62811   0   4294
238507  01.2136 62812   10  4294
238507  Umobile 62812   18  4294
238507  01.2136 62813   15  4294
238507  Umobile 62813   17  4294
```

please look the last column , it is all the same value . but i am sure the right result should be different base on different customer and prefix ,  i think the where condition happens some error , 
can anybody tell me how to fix it ?　thanks .

Comment: What does V_MeraRpt_Detail_ByPrefix contain? The subquery returns only the sum for reportID only for 2 reports ( rptID and lastRptID) Do you want to get all the SuccessCalls for each Customer and Prefix?

Comment: Use aliases for all tables and fields - I think that "where a.[BelongTo] = Customer and a.[Prefix] = Prefix" creates some problems - it compares fields to themselves, not to outer query fields.